# Using different Thread.sleep() duration to control Player speed?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, drawing

I am trying to drawLine() faster if one object in the "bikes" list contains a boolean isBoosting. When the list contains two bikes and the result is that both bikes seem to speed up when only one of the bikes "isBoosting". Does anyone have an idea as to why? Shouldn't the Thread "move" slower if the object does not contain the value true for isBoosting?

```
foreach (LightBike b in bikes) //draw bikes
{

    if (b.isBoosting && b.boostCounter > 0) //player is boosting
    {
         Thread.Sleep(GAME_SPEED - 5);
         b.boostCounter--;
         if (b.boostCounter == 0)
         {
             b.isBoosting = false;
             b.boostCounter = 20;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(GAME_SPEED);
    }

    canvas.DrawLine(new Pen(b.color, BIKE_SIZE) { EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square }, b.location, b.getNextLocation());

}
```

Comment: *This approach will not work reliably.* Do not control the delay: it is only an approximation and can be dominated by other factors and affects everything. *Control the amount moved for each time delta* (which is not exactly constant and can be varied once the time delta is handled correctly). This simple form of "time delta movement" is covered in any [good] basic game tutorial.

Comment: Also, the update logic should be separate from the draw logic: drawing is just a visual manifestation of the objects in the world and should be independent in most cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with this.

Firstly, since it's a single thread, when you sleep for a period the thread is descheduled--no rendering will be done (Which in your case means neither "boosted" bikes nor other bikes will be drawn). The lines that are actually drawn will always go from b.location to b.getNextLocation(), which are (I assume) equal for both boosted and unboosted bikes.

Secondly, you're mixing in logic with rendering code...

Really you should implement bikes as some sort of model and differentiate between bike-speed in the model and rendering, keeping that out of the rendering code.

Ideally that model would contain a speed-vector for each bike (which is modified by an acceleration vector at a tickcount, independent of the rendering cycle), and all the rendering would do is draw the appropriate line.

So basically put your boosting-code into b.getNextLocation() rather than in Draw(), and remove the conditional statement from the drawing code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are two bikes, A and B, (not boosting). Let's go through a couple of cycles:

```
A -- wait GAME_SPEED
Redraw A
B -- wait GAME_SPEED
Redraw B
A -- wait GAME_SPEED
Redraw A
B -- wait GAME_SPEED
Redraw B
```

Time between redraws of A = time between redraws of B = GAME_SPEED*2.

Now suppose B is boosting:

```
A -- wait GAME_SPEED
Redraw A
B -- wait GAME_SPEED - 5
Redraw B
A -- wait GAME_SPEED
Redraw A
B -- wait GAME_SPEED - 5
Redraw B
```

Time between redraws of B = time between redraws of A = GAME_SPEED*2 - 5.

This just shows you why what you're observing happens: each bike waits for everyone's delay, not just their own.

The only way to get around that is to have one "screen refresh" delay, and control the speed by changing the distance that objects move, not the time delay.